# Get {"message":"Unauthenticated."} when sending POST request to laravel server

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, axios

I have a problem with sending POST request from Vue axios to laravel server with sanctum.

Firstly I'm getting token.

My route of `api.php`

```
Route::post('/get_token', function (Request $request) {
    $request->validate([
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required',
        'device_name' => 'required'
    ]);
    $user = User::where('email', $request->email)->first();
    if (! $user || ! Hash::check($request->password, $user->password)) {
        throw ValidationException::withMessages([
            'email' => ['The provided credentials are incorrect.'],
        ]);
    }
    return $user->createToken($request->device_name)->plainTextToken;
});
```

`vue axios`

```
this.$axios.post('/api/get_token', {
    email: this.email,
    password: this.password,
    device_name: this.device_name,
}).then(response=>{...});
```

And when I send GET request with received token, it works correctly

`vue axios`

```
this.$axios.get('/api/book/all', {
    headers: {
        "Authorization": 'Bearer ' + this.$store.getters.getToken
    }
}).then(response=>{...})
```

`api.php`

```
Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->get('/book/all', 'BookController@all');
```

But when I try to send POST request, I get `{"message":"Unauthenticated."}` and 401 error

`vue axios`

```
this.$axios.post('/api/book/add', {
    headers: {
        "Authorization": 'Bearer ' + this.$store.getters.getToken,
    },
    data: {
        title: this.addingTitle,
        author: this.addingAuthor,
    }
})
```

`api.php`

```
Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->post('/book/add', 'BookController@add');
```

Sorry, I’m just a noob in web and don’t understand many things, hope you can help me.

Comment: Only `book/add` seems to require authorisation based on what you shared so the fact that `book/all` works doesn't indicate that it's a problem with only that other route

Comment: @apokryfos Yes, the problem can be not only with `book/add`, it's just the only post request in my project;) and if I try to send get request to `book/all` without token, I get {"message":"Unauthenticated."} too. Sorry for bad english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `post` then the 1st parameter is the URL and the 2nd one is the data your are posting. In your case it might make more sense to use:

```
this.$axios({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '/api/book/add'
    headers: {
        "Authorization": 'Bearer ' + this.$store.getters.getToken,
    },
    data: {
        title: this.addingTitle,
        author: this.addingAuthor,
    }
})
```

or if you want to still use `.post` then:

```
this.$axios.post('/api/book/add', {
        title: this.addingTitle,
        author: this.addingAuthor,
    }, {
    headers: {
        "Authorization": 'Bearer ' + this.$store.getters.getToken,
    }
})
```

Comment: thank you so much, I didn't suppose, that the problem is in front side